# font icons in drupal

Tags: 7, theming

I want to use font icons in some of the headings in my Drupal 7 website.

For that I have downloaded and enabled Fontello module along with icon module and enabled that. The module home page says that " ... upload the bundle via this module's configuration page " But there is no configuration page for this module.

Please guide me how to use icon fonts in Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used this module before, but from the info file it seems that the admin page is at

> admin/config/media/icon

and from there it looks like you upload at

> admin/config/media/icon/import